Help with Grid formatting
After completing my PhD, I am curiously looking at the stock market from outside for now. I have some plots created to look at the market. For simplicity, let's say
stocks = {"NASDAQ:MSFT", "NASDAQ:AMZN", "NASDAQ:GOOGL"};

plot1 = ParallelMap[
   TradingChart[#, PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> Medium] & , stocks];

plot2 = ParallelMap[
   DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "AdjustedClose", {2024, 4, 1}], 
     PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks];
plot3 = ParallelMap[
   DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "AdjustedOpen", {2024, 4, 1}] , 
     PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks];
plot4 = ParallelMap[
   DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "Volume", {2024, 4, 1}] , 
     PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks];

I have been looking at the plots as:
Grid[Partition[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}, 1], 
 Frame -> {{False, False}, All}]

However, I want to show them as below for each stock. Since plot1 is tall with several indicators, I want to show other plots sideways in each row.
Grid[{{plot1, SpanFromLeft, plot2}, {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth, 
   plot3}, {SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth, plot4}}, Frame -> All]

Thank you.

Not completely clear what you want, but I think you've made it too complicated:
stocks = {"NASDAQ:MSFT", "NASDAQ:AMZN", "NASDAQ:GOOGL"};

plot1 = Map[TradingChart[#, PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
  stocks]

plot2 = Map[
  DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "AdjustedClose", {2024, 4, 1}], 
    PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks]
plot3 = Map[
  DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "AdjustedOpen", {2024, 4, 1}], 
    PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks]
plot4 = Map[
  DateListPlot[FinancialData[#, "Volume", {2024, 4, 1}], 
    PlotLabel -> #] &, stocks]

Grid[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}, Frame -> All]

Which gives you:

Or perhaps this:
Grid[{
  {plot1[[1]], plot2[[1]], plot3[[1]], plot4[[1]]},
  {plot1[[2]], plot2[[2]], plot3[[2]], plot4[[2]]},
  {plot1[[3]], plot2[[3]], plot3[[3]], plot4[[3]]}}, Frame -> All]



Thank you @Jagra. The second row-wise version is what I was looking. I have several stocks and many plots and looking at column wise was getting out of hand.
